# Countifs with array criteria and multiple ranges

Tags: excel, range, spreadsheet, criteria, countif

I have three columns of Data. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpOSy.png)

I want to find a permutation where I can count the hits of data that satisfy 3 conditions

1) In column `C` the data belongs to the group defined as `Europe (I9:I12)`

2) In column `D` the data belongs to the group defined as `Asia (J9:J12)`

3) In column `B` the data is greater than year `2013 (L9)`

Basically trying to find the permutation of European countries that cross with Asian countries from `2013` to `2018`.

This is my formula as in the image, with Ctrl+Shift+Enter:

```
{=SUM(COUNTIFS($C:$C,I12:I15,$D:$D,J12:J15,$B:$B,">="&$L$12))}
```

But gives me 0 at the moment when should find and count 2 results

For interest, my next step would be finding the other way round, cross between `Asian` and `Europe`.

I appreciate very much the help

Comment: Can you explain why the formula you posted references the range Transactions!$M:$M, which does not appear to be included in your accompanying explanations?

Comment: Also, perhaps you could add what the expected result for that dataset SHOULD be.

Comment: @XORLX Now updates

Answer (score 2):

`=SUM(COUNTIFS($C:$C,I12:I15,$D:$D,TRANSPOSE(J12:J15),$B:$B,">="&$L$12))`

One of the two arrays needs to be transposed such that it is orthogonal to the other. See here for an explanation if you like:

https://excelxor.com/2014/09/28/countifs-multiple-or-criteria-for-one-or-two-criteria_ranges/

Regards

Comment: This is amazing! Works perfectly